# Generating a quadratic polynomial in RSA (cryptosystem)

Tags: cryptography

Question: Suppose that *n* is the product of distinct primes *p* and *q*, so *n*=*pq*

Show that *p* and *q* are the roots of the quadratic equation

x^2 -(*n*+1 -φ(*n*))x + *n*

Hence if *n* and φ(*n*) are known then *n* can be easily factored.

So far I know that φ(*n*)=(*p*-1)(*q*-1) and that φ(*n*)= #{1≤x≤n : gcd(x,n)=1}

Any guidance on how to proceed to start generating this quadratic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use Vieta's formulas to verify that $p+q=n+1-\phi (n)$ and substitute $p=\frac{n}{q}$ in your equation. The same for $q=\frac{n}{p}$.

Comment: If you can't figure it out on your own, let me know. :)

Comment: Thank you very much Lullaby for your input :) greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when $A,B$ are the roots of $x^2 + ax + b = 0$, we know that $(x-A)(x-B) = x^2 + ax + b$, and so $x^2 - (A+B)x + AB = x^2 + ax + b$ (for all $x$), so that $a = -(A + B), b = AB$, or $A+B = -a, AB = b$. So the coefficients of the quadratic are just the negative sum of the roots, and their product respectively.

When $n = pq$, we know that $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq - (p+q) + 1 = n - (p+q) + 1$.
Hence $p+q = n - \phi(n) + 1$, and so we know that $p,q$ are the roots of $x^2 - (p+q) + pq = x^2 - (n + 1 - \phi(n)) + n$.

Comment: Thank you it should have occurred to me roots of polynomial equations that the sum of the roots say alpha and beta is equal to -b/a and the product is equal to c/a where the coefficients are a,b,c i.e ax^2+bx+c thank you for reminding me :)